# Environments in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have read that deploying an application on development environment may be one of the worst cases, but i couldn't find any real information about HOW i can change the environments of my applications and make their production databases ready?

I am using Passenger/Nginx for deployment by the way.

Edit : People you get it wrong, maybe i asked wrong, i know how to change environments by nginx, but if i change it from nginx and don't touch to my app, it crashes. There are some things i have to done to my app before i change their environment from development to production, i want info about them.

Comment: where are you trying to run your app? by default it is development but you can just add a RAILS_ENV-production when you run your server

Comment: on my dev machines i am running it by default, which i think is developent. But at the deployment i have no idea how to make my app's ready for deployment. At least i know that i should make their environments production, but i couldn't find any information about that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your virtual host put following environment variable:-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/apache2/htdocs/tutorial/Web/
  ServerName dev.tutorial.local
  SetEnv FLOW3_CONTEXT Production
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#RailsEnv

From the Passenger documentation, RAILS_ENV defaults to production.

If not you can specify it in the nginx configuration:

- In the ***http*** configuration block.
- In a ***server*** configuration block.
- In a ***location*** configuration block.
- In an ***if*** configuration scope.

Comment: I know changing from nginx but it is not complete solution, there must be other steps, because my app's crash if i DON'T change the RAILS_ENV to development

Comment: Then the problem may be elsewhere. Is there any information in your logs when it crashes in production?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. but try changing environment varaible in config/environment.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'
```